# Unable to Access Multiple Websites (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED) from Home WiFi on Desktop PC

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, firefox, vpn

I've recently run into a puzzling issue. Unexpectedly, my desktop computer has started having trouble accessing several websites (more than just a handful). Here are the error messages I see when trying to navigate to these pages:

[Error Screenshot](https://ibb.co/zs0gf11)

- Firefox: Hmmm…can't reach this page
- Opera: This site can't be reached
- Chrome: This site can't be reached (ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED)
- Edge: Can’t connect securely to this page

**Further details:**

- The issue only occurs when using Wi-Fi at home. Wired connections via
  ethernet work perfectly.
- This problem is specific to my home Wi-Fi; no issues arise when
  connected to alternative Wi-Fi networks.
- Running Windows 10, HP model.
- Network Adapter: Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless LAN 802.11n PCI-E NIC.

**Other relevant information:**

- No range extender or signal booster is in use.
- No other device on my network experiences similar problems.

**Attempted solutions with outcomes:**

- Manually removing the desktop from the router's interface (DIDN'T
  WORK)
- Resetting the router (DIDN'T WORK)
- Switching routers (DIDN'T WORK)
- Trying varying OS and browser configurations (DIDN'T WORK)
- Uninstalling and reinstalling network adapter drivers (DIDN'T WORK)
- Accessing via WiFi USB dongle network adapter (WORKED)
- Using an Ethernet connection (WORKED)
- Connection through alternate WiFi networks (WORKED)
- Utilizing VPN for access(WORKED)

There appears to be no clear commonality between the websites that aren't accessible for me. Here are a few of them as examples:

- https://www.formulapassion.it/
- https://www.techrum.vn/
- https://www.isup.me/
- https://randomoutputs.com/
- https://torrentgalaxy.to/
- https://www.grabcad.com/

Comment: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED usually means that your PC/the DNS server you're "connected" to, can't find the IP address of the domain. You can check which DNS servers you're connected to with this powershell command: `Get-DnsClientServerAddress`, and update the question with the results.

Comment: “Connection through alternate WiFi networks” - Please explain this, do you mean, another internet connection or a different access point connected to the same internet connection?

Comment: Please include the picture in the question. That strange image link does not embed.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a DNS issue. Try doing this and see if it works.

Go to https://mxtoolbox.com/DnsLookup.aspx

Put in the website you are having issues with, for example "formulapassion.it"

Then see if you can access the website from the IP address. (may or may not load on everything depending on how the server handles request) But if you get something to load then it's your DNS.

You could try restarting your modem and router, checking your modem/router to see what DNS they are using. Change that to another public DNS service, then flush the DNS on Windows and see if it works.